# How can I say "love" without character or digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Inspired by Ryan Barnett's PPT of BlackHat DC 2011, especially the code below:

```
($=[$=[]][(__=!$+$)[_=-~-~-~$]+({}+$)[_/_]+ ($$=($_=!''+$)[_/_]+$_[+$])])()[__[_/_]+__ [_+~$]+$_[_]+$$](_/_)
```

Yesterday was special day for lovers, so I tried to write something similar. Which basically alert "I love you" without any character or digits.

e.g. "I" can be obtained from    `((_=-~[])/--_+[])[_]`

we have "[object Object]", "true", "false", "NaN", "Infinity" to use, I cannot figure out a way to get "v" this way.

I tried to think of `String.fromCharCode()`, (Ryan already get `window` reference for us, so in theory, we can `window["String"]["fromCharCode"](118)`) however I miss "S" and "C" character here. Also think about `window["eval"](...)`, again, I have no "v".

Just try to explain a little bit, `[]` is empty, when apply `+/-/~` operate to it, it converts to number `0`, and `~[]` gives `1`, `1/0` gives `Infinitey`. Then it comes to `1/0 + []`, they will both converted to string for the add, which gives `"Infinity"`, and `"Infinity"[_] == "Infinity"[0] == "I"`...

The original code of Ryan is more complex, it utilized a lot more, includes scope, special return value, etc. (this is another story)

This might not seem to be a great idea to do things, but just very interesting.

With help with meze, I was able to produce this for Firefox:

```
($=($=[$=[]][(__=!$+$)[_=-~-~-~$]+(_$={}+$)[_/_]+ ($$=($_=!''+$)[_/_]+$_[+$])])())[__[_/_]+__ [_+~$]+$_[_]+$$]((_$_=(__$=-~[])/--__$+[])[__$]+_$[_+++_]+__[__$=-~-~[]]+_$[-~[]]+($[_$[$__=_+_]+_$[++$__]+_$[++$__]+_$[++$__]+_$[++$__]+_$[++$__]]+[])[
$__+$__+--_]+__[++_]+_$[$__=_+--_]+_$_[_+++_]+_$[_/_]+$_[__$]);
```

it basically is `alert("I love you")`, many thanks! If only I get the help yesterday, which I have not post this yet :(

JavaScript is beautiful, some varibles for your reference:

```
$_ = "true"
__ = "false"
_$ = "[object Object]"
$$ = "rt"
_$_ = "Infinity"
_ = 3 = 4 = 3 = 4 = 3
$  = window
$__ = 8  = 13
__$  = 0 = 2
```

Some variables are reused many times, will not try to leave details, it is not a fun job :) I am happy, we are finally here! This actually has lots of potential, as we now have "v", and lots of digits, we will in theory possible to `eval()` lots of... things easier. I will show this to my wife, hope she enjoys the _$-+()...

example as your reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wqw/

btw, we can shorten the code a bit, as we already have reference to `sort()`, which can be used instead of window["Object"] to get the "native code" => "v", here it is:

```
($=($_$=($=[$=[]][(__=!$+$)[_=-~-~-~$]+(_$={}+$)[_/_]+ ($$=($_=!''+$)[_/_]+$_[+$])]))())[__[_/_]+__ [_+~$]+$_[_]+$$]((_$_=(__$=-~[])/--__$+[])[__$]+_$[_+++_]+__[__$=-~-~[]]+_$[-~[]]+($_$+[])[(__$<<__$<<__$)-_+~[]]+$_[--_]+_$[$__=_+++_]+_$_[_+--_]+_$[_/_]+$_[__$]);
```

Again, it works only in Firefox, might not try to migrate to other browser. And I love Firefox.

Comment: Please, don't use the tag "j" for JavaScript and JavaScript-related technologies.

Comment: One of the related questions to right is *Why does it say xxx is not a function*.... I knew it, SO is all about love and xxx :D

Comment: Related: Mathematical equations saying "Love" http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2011/02/13/wolframalpha-in-love/

Comment: How do you plan on using `eval`?

Comment: oh so it came the time js became worst than bf.

Comment: Being more of a programming puzzle than a real problem, wouldn't this be a better fit for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I was thinking about eval() and soon find out that I have no "v" for it, thus have not go to details...you can do it like this: []+(window["eval"]('_$$="\x76"')&&_$$)

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed, it was very popular. Also, for the record - this is a programming "forum" and this is a programming question...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well at least in Firefox, JavaScript native objects return `function Object() {  [native code] }`, which has 'v'. So if we have `window` and `Object`, then i suppose we could do:

```
(window["Object"]+0)[29];
```

Comment: it's got characters AND digits...

Comment: this is a very good way, will try, thanks

Comment: @Daniel... it has already been shown that digits are easily produced, and so is the string 'Object'.

Comment: Great idea... I took it and made it work with Chrome too: `(window["Object"]+'')['match'](/\[.*/)[0][5]` - anyone have IE to test it on?

Comment: IE8/IE9 RC works, but not [29], need index [30], IE7 seems not like it. All above is done in IE9 RC different mode.

Answer (score 6):

Same message, but different spelling.

```
// "I <3 u"
_= +~[]; // 1
__= -[]; // 0
___= +(-~[] -~[] -~[]); // 3
$=''
+(''+(_/__))[__] // i
+' ' // space
+'<'+___ // <3
+' ' // space
+(''+(_<__))[+(-~[] -~[])]; // u
alert($);
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t7sPB/1/)

Answer (score 6):

```
alert("\u2665"); // results in ♥
```

Answer (score 4):

try this code:

```
$=(Å='',[Ç=!(µ=!Å+Å)+{}][Ç[È=++Å-~Å]+Ç[È+È]+µ[Å]+µ[Å-Å]])();
_=$[Ç[È+È+Å]+µ[Å-Å]+Ç[È+È]+Ç[Å]]("¾");
console.info( _[+[]] ); // concole is used just to show result ;)
```

if you run it, on the console you will get "v" :), more info about it can be found [there](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,28687,page=1)

there is a way to avoid "¾", but result will be "V" (actually nothing bad for such a word like love :):

```
$=(Å='',[Ç=!(µ=!Å+Å)+{}][Ç[È=++Å-~Å]+Ç[È+È]+µ[Å]+µ[Å-Å]])(); // we get window object
_=$[Ç[È+È+Å]+µ[Å-Å]+Ç[È+È]+Ç[Å]]( $ ); // we use btoa function with argument "[object Window]", 
// and it returns "W29iamVjdCBXaW5kb3dd" - as you see there is V 
$$=-~!''; // 2
$$$=-~$$; // 3
console.info( _[$$*$$$] ); // "V";
```

`btoa` creates encoded data from the given string, using base-64 encoding. Actually playing with that function and changing arguments you can get different characters :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, it uses `btoa`. But I don't like the "¾" part, it's a character ;(

Comment: your code is very impressive, which I cannot easily understand at all... when unicode joins the party, it is more fun :)

Comment: @ccppjava: I tried to explain a bit, hope that will help you to create other sentences with "no alpha digital" javascript ;)

Comment: @meze: no "¾" anymore, but result is "V"..

Comment: window.btoa() is the interesting bit here, learn something new everyday :) thanks.

Comment: The opposite of `window.btoa` is `window.atob` :)